# Angular-highcharts colors. Is there any way to get color besides Highcharts.getOptions().colors[index]?

Tags: javascript, angular, highcharts

Already solved, but just wondering, is there any way to get an access to the highcharts colors besides Highcharts.getOptions()?

Here is the situation:

```
series: [{
  name: 'Some Name',
  data: [{
    name: 'Something 1',
     ...
    color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[3]
}, {
    name: 'Something 2',
    ...
    color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[4]
  }]
}]
```

I use angular-highcharts (https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-highcharts).

If I use regular Highcharts, this will work.

In Angular-highcharts this works as well, but only if I render charts after I set the theme.
But in my situation, charts are generated in the template using *ngFor, so Highcharts.getOptions().colors[3] returns color of default color scheme.

Also, I provided color for every chart, using 'colors' property. 
My question is: how I can access to the color of the particular chart?

```
new Chart({
  chart: {
      ...
    },
    colors: this.chartColorPalette,
    series: [{
    ...
  }]
}),
```

Of course, I already solved this issue by directly accessing to this.chartColorPalette array, but is there any other way to do the same thing?

I mean, something like Highcharts.getOptions().colors[index]?
Or is it possible to set the palette (theme) before rendering the view template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you need to set the colors of specific chart directly in the chart configuration object, instead in `chart.colors`, because most probably this setup won't work automatically.

Regarding your question about getting the colors of specific chart (not global Highcharts object), you should be able to access `options.colors` on `Chart` object, for example that:

```
chart: {
  events: {
    load() {
      console.log(this.options.colors)  
    }
  }
}
```

I have to notice, it depends on the scope where you would try to access the chart object.

**Live example:** https://jsfiddle.net/dexkhb97/